# Delete Duplicate Records with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my Table Structure with data:

```
ID   Date                       EmpId

67   2015-08-24 10:44:33.087    293
68   2015-08-24 10:41:49.950    293
69   2015-08-24 10:42:49.951    293
70   2015-08-24 10:45:15.157    013
71   2015-08-24 10:46:33.131    013
72   2015-08-24 10:42:33.134    013
73   2015-08-24 10:47:33.136    013
```

ID Column is a auto generated column. 
For every employee there are 2 or more than 2 records. In this case. EmpId - 293 has got three records. 013 has got 4 records. I am looking for a query to return record with maximum Date for every employee. In this case the result should be as below:

```
ID    Date                        EmpId

69    2015-08-24 10:44:33.087     293
73    2015-08-24 10:47:33.136     013
```

My requirement is to return all 3 columns in the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ID,Date,EMPID
from (
    select ID, Date, EMPId, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by EMPId order by Date desc) as RowNUm
    from Employee
) A
where RowNUm = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH TempId
AS (
  SELECT *, 
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY ID desc) AS [Num]
  FROM Employee1
)
DELETE TempId WHERE [Num] > 1  --For deleting record

Select * from Employee1   --For Selecting record
```

Find solution in Fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80f3d/3

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM (select ID 
                    ,Date
                    , EMPId
                    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by EMPId order by Date desc) as RowNum 
                    from Employee) WHERE RowNum > 1
```

Above query will remove any duplicate `empid` (the older one).

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me:

```
SELECT
t.ID, t._Date, t.EmpId
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN test t_theta 
  ON t.EmpId = t_theta.EmpId 
  AND t._Date < t_theta._Date
WHERE
  t_theta.ID IS NULL
```

Basically, you use a theta join to join the table to itself.  Then, you limit it to return records in the first table where there are no greater dates for that employee ID in the second table.  Enjoy!

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd2b1/1